# How to close a content page on button click and remove that from stack in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

want to close a content page on button click and remove it from stack,so how to achieve this.PopAsync is not working for me.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code? PopAsync is the best way to do this generally.  Are you using a navigation page?

Answer (score 1):

To remove some page of you navigation stack you can use.

```
this.Navigation.RemovePage (this.Navigation.NavigationStack [your page index]);
```

but if you just want to go back screen or go to main page of your navigation stack you can use this.

```
this.Navigation.PopAsync ();
this.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call

```
Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
```

from async void.
for example if you have button click handler just add async keyword before void like this:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();

   }
```

Comment: A code without any explanation whatsoever is not recommended.